# How to properly handle server-side errors in Next.js 14?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, server-action

I'm working on a Next.js 14 project, and I have a setup where I make API requests using fetch in a `handler.tsx` file like this:

```
async function getPositions() {
  const response = await fetch(
    process.env.BASE_API_URL + "/positions?enabled=true",
    {
      cache: "no-cache",
    }
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Es gab ein Problem mit Ihrer Anfrage");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  return data.result;
}

export { getPositions };
```

In my page file `page.tsx` I simply call the `getPositions` function and assume that any server-side errors will be caught in a global error handler:

```
import { getPositions } from "./handler";

export default async function Page() {
  const positions = await getPositions();

  console.log(positions);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Positions</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

According to the Next.js documentation, it seems like I don't have to catch the error explicitly and can let it propagate through to be caught in a separate error handler `error.tsx`. Is this approach correct and are there any best practices for handling server-side errors in Next.js 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine approach

However you can add your error.jsx closer to your page to prevent disabling full ui to your users

Comment: Thx, is it normal that the next js still shows the error in the console and with its red toast in the bottom left?

Comment: Yes, this is normal behavior, it show to help you debugging errors, in production build, there will no such error explanations

Comment: All right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this in Next 14 , APP router , server side

```js
return NextResponse.json({message:Internal Server error, status:500})
```